# Eclipse EGit with dark background, still has black text

Tags: eclipse, egit, eclipse-luna

*My apologies if Stackoverflow was the incorrect Stackexchange site for this IDE-related question*.

I am working on a project, which is shared with Git, on **Eclipse Luna**. As such, I rely on the **EGit** plugin for Git integration in the IDE (note that I have installed the latest version of EGit, 3.5). I prefer using dark colour themes in my IDEs, so I am using **[Moonrise UI](http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/)** and **[Eclipse Color Themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/)** plugins to enable this behaviour.

It all works fine, my IDE is dark and colours within the toolbars and menu are not abnormal. However, there are still problems with the EGit colouring in my Package Explorer. The main issue is that certain text in the Package Explorer is now coloured black (this is being done on directories and files that have been edited). And this is against a black background. This makes it near impossible to see the text that is being coloured.

I know that I can change this colouring manually by going into Preferences --> General --> Appearance --> Colors And Fonts, select Git, and change all actions resulting in the colour black to be a different colour instead. However, I find this to be a little tedious and I thought that perhaps there is a more intuitive way to have these colours changed dynamically to make more sense against a dark background. I am also having these thoughts because this issue has already been reported as a [bug in EGit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430741) that should have been fixed by version 3.5.

Any insight into this issue I'm facing is much appreciated.

Comment: A related answer that documents my un-desired workaround (no offence to the answer, it is a great one, I'm just looking for something more dynamic than this as my accepted answer): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84248/darcula-dark-theme-for-eclipse

Comment: add screen shot please

Comment: Any news here @ecbrodie? Still getting black text here with EGit 3.6.2 with a dark theme. Did you discover some workaround?

Comment: I've had to rely on changing the preferences manually, as outlined in my question.

Comment: @ecbrodie, do you still have this problem?

Comment: I am not using Eclipse as my IDE anymore, so I am unable to comment if I am still facing this issue. I have accepted the best answer based on what I remember working for me at the time.

Comment: 10/2018 same issue hahaha nice bug fixing

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to edit the Eclipse Theme. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Appearance > Colors and Fonts. Search by Uncommitted Change (Foreground), edit and choose your preferred color.

Comment: "Ignored resources" is another one with a dark font, so get that one too while you are at it.

Comment: The MercurialEclipse plugin has similar problems and this solution works as well but you need to browse for "MercurialEclipse".

Comment: For *MercurialEclipse* (*Eclipse 4.17* with *MercurialEclipse 2.12.0*): `Window -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> MercurialEclipse` **`Changed (Foreground)`** (was `rgb(0,0,0)`) changed to ***rgb( 0, 128, 255 )*** (light blue). Had to `Apply and close` and eventually refresh or reopen the *Project Explorer* view to make it work.

Answer (score 11):

I use regular Git which also gave black text. You can completely disable it in Preferences > Appearance > Label Decorations where you uncheck Git.

I don't think it is possible to disable Git text change but keep the '>' changes.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of disabling the feature all-together you can keep Git decorators enabled and modify a few settings. You will still be able to see the theme's correct colors and there are only 2 things you must change:

1. Go to Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Git.
2. Select "Uncommitted Change (Foreground)".
3. Set to about 72% white on a black vs white slide bar.
4. Select "Ignored Resource (Foreground)".
5. Set to about 72% white on a black vs white slide bar.
6. Click Apply and Okay.

You should be good to go and will have the freedom to configure whatever colors you wish to show the "Ignored" fields and the "Uncommitted Change" fields.

We are developers here... Not feature killers...

Comment: I used different colors, but thanks for the pointers on which items to look for!

Answer (score 3):

As long as all the other fonts and colors are to your liking in in Eclipse - go to...

**`Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations`**

Uncheck Git and why not SVN while you're at it.

This should clear everything up for EGit.

You may also find that unchecking other items in this section will clear up other font/color issues you might have.

Comment: This is like killing a fly with dynamite.. You lose uncommited changes indication, one of the most interesting features of EGit, IMO. not worth it..

Answer (score -2):

Use another tool for git management (like Sourcetree or even  the cli git) and disconnect your project by right clicking on it, going to the Team menu and selecting "disconnect" from it. Works fine for me that way, since I'm used to use the cli git.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse as my scm manager. I will often use CLI git or Sourcetree for running my got commands. However, it is common for IDEs to use basic UI features to reflect status of git management. It is for convenience.

Comment: Well, the problem you have is a KNOWN BUG on eclipse theme, and I suggested you to disconnect your project on Eclipse only. Since it's a BUG, asking on Stackoverflow how to solve a products BUG won't get any useful answer.